# SQL Server error 80040e14 Using Classic ASP in a Result Set

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I'm trying to select results from a database for each position of a vector using classic ASP and SQL Server. The code so far:

```
FOR EACH x IN Tabela

    sql = "SELECT DISTINCT tborders.family AS family, tborders.qty AS qty, tborders.los AS los, CONVERT(DATE, tborders.mrd_date) AS mrd FROM [DASH].[dashboard_db].[dbo].[tb_family] AS tbfamily INNER JOIN [DASH].[dashboard_db].[dbo].[tb_started_zero] AS tborders ON tbfamily.[family] = tborders.[family] WHERE tborders.[Order Number] = "&x&""
    SET rs = conn.execute(sql)

    IF rs.EOF = false THEN
        mrd(counter) = rs("mrd") 
        family(counter) = rs("family") 
        los(counter) = rs("los") 
        qty(counter) = rs("qty") 
        counter=counter+1
    END IF

NEXT
```

Taking note that `tborders.[Order Number]` is a `int` typed value. For some reason I'm having this error:

> Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 error '80040e14'
>
> Incorrect syntax near '='.
>
> /asplearning/act/validate-schedule-line.asp, line 46

I have tried removing the `SET`, but then my result set isn't recognized as a object. I'm pretty sure that the types are just fine, I have tried:

```
if isNumeric(x) THEN
        response.write("<h1>it is numeric</h1>")
        else
        response.write("<h1>not numeric</h1>")
    end if
```

And it has written "it is numeric" for each position of `Tabela`. Can anyone help with what it seems to be the problem?

Comment: You really should look into using parameters instead of building up a string. Also, doing this type of thing in a for each loop is an indication you might consider doing this set based instead of RBAR (row by agonizing row).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's look you have an empty item (first or last item of the collection).

I strongly suggest you to use sp_executesql.  This will use a compiled execution plan, and this will validate your parameters (against sql injection).

```
FOR EACH x IN Tabela
    if len(x) > 0 then
        sql = "exec sp_executeSql N'SELECT DISTINCT tborders.family AS family, tborders.qty AS qty, tborders.los AS los, CONVERT(DATE, tborders.mrd_date) AS mrd FROM [DASH].[dashboard_db].[dbo].[tb_family] AS tbfamily INNER JOIN [DASH].[dashboard_db].[dbo].[tb_started_zero] AS tborders ON tbfamily.[family] = tborders.[family] WHERE tborders.[Order Number] = @OrderNumber', N'@OrderNumber int', @orderNumber = " & x
        SET rs = conn.execute(sql)

        IF rs.EOF = false THEN
            mrd(counter) = rs("mrd") 
            family(counter) = rs("family") 
            los(counter) = rs("los") 
            qty(counter) = rs("qty") 
            counter=counter+1
        END IF
        rs.close
    end if
NEXT
```

Comment: Thank you! I will surely look into NOT building a string for the query. It is really messy. And exec sp_executeSql is really handy. Also, thank you for answering. Most people are very reversal to old technologies and down-vote questions just for having it as a tag.